# object type 'int' has no len() in 2D array printing

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm new here, but I thought someone might be able to help me with something I have been working on for a little while now.

I'm creating a lotto game where players and the winning numbers are created using random numbers. While i have been doing this i got the winning numbers to work but the 2D array for the players is not working properly and is not printing properly could i get some help on debugging the issue

```
I want to create a table like below

Player ID    Player Numbers 
  1          8, 26, 24, 25, 30, 16, 25, 30
  2          15, 11, 9, 0, 8, 17, 19, 18
  3          13, 6, 18, 14, 29, 21, 13, 10
```

When i compile my current code it gives me the below error

```
all the players
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/User Profile/Documents/runner.py", line 66, in <module>
    lottoPlayers()
  File "E:/User Profile/Documents/runner.py", line 46, in lottoPlayers
    printPlayers(players)
  File "E:/User Profile/Documents/runner.py", line 40, in printPlayers
    for j in range(len(array[i])):
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

My code is as below

```
import random


def random_generator():
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, 30)
    return randomNumber
def generate_players():
    players = []
    for i in range(10):
        for i in range(8):
            randomNumber = random_generator()
            players.append(randomNumber)
    return players

def printPlayers(array):
    for i in range(len(array)):
        for j in range(len(array[i])): # the error looked to me like it was coming from here but i dont get it why as im doing something similar above and no errors popped-up
            print(array[i][j], end=' ')
        print()
        
def lottoPlayers():
    players = generate_players()
    print("all the players")
    printPlayers(players)

lottoPlayers()
```

please not that this is only the code for the player creation if need the code for the rest of the program for the debug please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import random


def random_generator():
    randomNumber = random.randint(0, 30)
    return randomNumber
def generate_players():
    players=[]
    for i in range(10):
        t=[]
        for j in range(8):
            r=random_generator()
            t.append(r)
        players.append(t)
    return players
      
p=generate_players()
for i in range(len(p)):
    print(i+1,"    ",p[i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem lies in those lines:

```
    for i in range(10):
        for i in range(8):
            randomNumber = random_generator()
            players.append(randomNumber)
```

there are two `for i`, I guess it should be `for i (...) for j`.

Most importantly, `players` is here defined as a 1D array, but it seems you intend to define a 2D array.